# error CS0103: The name does not exist in the current context; system doesn't recognize that my list

Tags: c#, list

This is for an assignment in my object oriented programming class.

I am a beginner, especially with this language, so a lot of things could be wrong with this code.

For now, I am focusing on the error it keeps giving me when I run it: error CS0103: "The name `StudentList' does not exist in the current context."

I thought that by making my list public, this issue wouldn't occur.

It gives this error for every object that I try to add to the list in MainClass. This is my first time using lists in C#. Am I missing something pretty obvious? How do I fix this?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

class MainClass {
  public static void Main (string[] args) {
    Course Astronomy = new Course("115", "Astronomy", "Allen");
    StudentList.Add(new Student("Mark", "Johnson", 94.6));
    StudentList.Add(new Student("Marcy", "Steinfield", 89.2));
    StudentList.Add(new Student("Jennifer", "Fox", 98.7));
    StudentList.Add(new Student("Cody", "Fields", 84.3));
    StudentList.Add(new Student("Blake", "Patterson", 78.4));
    StudentList.Add(new Student("Brittany", "Cox", 91.8));
    StudentList.Add(new Student("Paul", "Sims", 90.0));
    Astronomy.roll();
  }
}
public class Student {
    
  public string fname;
  public string lname;
  public int avg;
  public Student() {
  }
  public Student(string fname, string lname, double avg) {
    fname = fname;
    lname = lname;
    avg = avg;
  }
}
public class Course {
  public List<Student> StudentList = new List<Student>();
  public string ccode;
  public string cname;
  public string teacher;
  
  public Course() {
  }
  public Course(string ccode, string cname, string teacher) {
    ccode = ccode;
    cname = cname;
    teacher = teacher;
  }
  public object addStudent(object sdnt) {

    return sdnt;
  }
  public void roll() {
    Console.WriteLine($"{cname} {ccode} Roster:\n");
    foreach(var student in StudentList) {
      Console.WriteLine($"{student.fname}\n");
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: `StudentList` is a property of `Course` - so you have to access it by `Astronomy.StudentList`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you try to access `StudentList` in `MainClass` but your list declaration `public List<Student> StudentList = new List<Student>();` is in the different class.

Try this:

```
class MainClass
{
    public static List<Student> StudentList = new List<Student>();

    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Course Astronomy = new Course("115", "Astronomy", "Allen");
        StudentList.Add(new Student("Mark", "Johnson", 94.6));
        StudentList.Add(new Student("Marcy", "Steinfield", 89.2));
        StudentList.Add(new Student("Jennifer", "Fox", 98.7));
        StudentList.Add(new Student("Cody", "Fields", 84.3));
        StudentList.Add(new Student("Blake", "Patterson", 78.4));
        StudentList.Add(new Student("Brittany", "Cox", 91.8));
        StudentList.Add(new Student("Paul", "Sims", 90.0));
        Astronomy.roll();
    }
}
```

Or this:

```
    class MainClass
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Course Astronomy = new Course("115", "Astronomy", "Allen");
        Astronomy.StudentList.Add(new Student("Mark", "Johnson", 94.6));
        Astronomy.StudentList.Add(new Student("Marcy", "Steinfield", 89.2));
        Astronomy.StudentList.Add(new Student("Jennifer", "Fox", 98.7));
        Astronomy.StudentList.Add(new Student("Cody", "Fields", 84.3));
        Astronomy.StudentList.Add(new Student("Blake", "Patterson", 78.4));
        Astronomy.StudentList.Add(new Student("Brittany", "Cox", 91.8));
        Astronomy.StudentList.Add(new Student("Paul", "Sims", 90.0));
        Astronomy.roll();
    }
}
```

Comment: This is a comment, not an answer. Can you show the corrected code.

Answer (score 0):

You already have a stub addStudent method that you can extend and use:

```
public Student AddStudent(Student sdnt) {
    this.StudentList.Add(sdnt);
    return sdnt;
}
```

I changed the type of the parameter from `object` to `Student` and added the supplied student to the list. This is the `StudentList` that is a field in the containing `Course` class.
Plus I changed the name to start with a capital letter (PascalCasing), as is standard for C#.

Usage:

```
Course astronomy = new Course("115", "Astronomy", "Allen");
astronomy.AddStudent(new Student("Mark", "Johnson", 94.6));
astronomy.AddStudent(new Student("Marcy", "Steinfield", 89.2));
// etc
```

Returning the added student (as you did) from AddStudent is not required, but not an error either. Right now the returned value is ignored.